# SQL Number rows of table in function (should be easy)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to number the rows of a table returned by a query. More specifically my function randomizes the rows of a table. I want an extra column which counts from 1-n AFTER the randomization is done. Here is my current code for the randomize function:

```
create or replace function random_surnames(num integer)
returns table(name character(30)) as
$$
begin 
    RETURN QUERY
    select public."Surname".surname
    from public."Surname" 
    order by random()
    Limit num;
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql' volatile;`
```

It should be simple enough, I just can't seem to be able to find a solution online maybe because I'm not using the correct keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using ROW_NUMBER and a subquery, here is an example of converting your query to do that:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () FROM
(select public."Surname".surname
from public."Surname" 
order by random()
Limit num) subq;
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds... :) +1

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot, I was confused for over 1 hour on this! Now it makes sense. @JorgeCampos thanks for the edit as well